# What would be an optimal design for my database?

Tags: sql, database

I need to build a small database for a school project and I'd like some advice. My database will only contain a few species and the forest(s) in which they can be found; I need to know the species' name, its population, the [IUCN assessment](http://www.iucnredlist.org/), the forest(s) it can be found it, and whether or not it is endemic to that forest.

The normal way one would go about doing this is to have a Species table, a Forests table, and a Forests_Species table to handle the many-to-many relations. However, I *know* I won't ever need that level of complexity in my database: there will only be three forests, and I'll make sure that each species only lives in one of these three. With that in mind, is it okay if I design my database like this (only a Species table that contains all the information)?

```
CREATE TABLE `Species` (
  `id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `population` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `conservation` enum('EX','EW','CR','EN','VU','NT','LC') NOT NULL,
  `forest` enum('Amazon', 'Bialowieza', 'Madagascar') NOT NULL,
  `endemic` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Edit: I also know that the database won't ever need to be updated, which means I won't need to invest time and effort to make it maintainable. Again, is it alright for me to design it like this, knowing it won't ever have to be maintained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're ok with never being able to have more than one forest per species, then this approach is fine. Removing joins is good.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,

If you are sure that you'll never have to add new forest and always you;ll have to choose among these three, than this is good solution because there is no joins between tables and the results will be retrieved faster. 
However because the database is too small (only two tables) this will not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it really depends on the domain problem you are trying to solve here.

If you are the GOD :) where you can ensure each species only exists in one forest, then I see nothing wrong with your design here. The simpler the better.

However, if you are going to have species that exist in more than one forest **OR** add new forest(s) in the future, then you might want to refactor it out to have a `Forest` table and a junction table (many-to-many) between `Species` table and `Forest` table.

Answer (score 0):

If you're that comfortable with your constraints, why do you

- have an integer primary key
- have no unique constraint on "name"

?

Comment: Because I'm not a database designer and I don't really intend to become one. I'm focusing on improving my coding skills instead. Now that you mention it though, I should probably remove the id and make the name the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I find confusing in your description.

First you say, `My database will only contain a few species and the forest(s) in which they can be found`, that is you seem to allow it to be more than one forest for a species to inhabit. But later you say, `I'll make sure that each species only lives in one of these three [forests]`. Now it seems to be confusing what you are actually intending it to be.

When that bit is settled, I'll be able to tell you whether you need to have the `endemic` column or not, because if you go with having every species living in only one forest that will automatically make them all endemic, won't it?

Also, going back to where you say, 'I'll make sure...', did you mean that you were not going to implement that as part of the database design?

Comment: I already know all the species I'll list, and each resides in only one forest. Also there's only ten of them for every forest (which makes a total of 30 species), so there won't even be that much data to handle. And no, it won't make them endemic. Each species can only be found in one of the three forests I list, but that doesn't mean they can't be found in others I didn't include in my database.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, I went a bit too far about endemics, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it properly. Just because you know the requirements won't ever change, doesn't mean they won't! For all you know* a new requirement may crop up when you have finished the project and adopting a proper approach could make all the difference!

With relatively small tables the speed difference will be negligible.

If it's a school project then, if the teacher is going to look at your solution, they will almost certainly want to see a "proper" approach. Or at least some explanation why you didn't do it the normal way.

(*) In this case you might genuinely know that the requirements won't creep, but in a real-life coding job they nearly always do!

Comment: Which is why in real life I would never do something like this. :)